# Why does Resharper offer to "Remove Unreachable Code" here?

Tags: c#, resharper

Inspecting the project I've inherited with Resharper, it first suggested I wrap this:

```
if (cellRng != null)
```

...around some code, so that cellRng is only acted on if it's not null. But after doing that, it tells me that "if block" code is not reachable, anyway. Here is the code in context:

```
if (cellRng != null)
{
    cellRng.Font.Bold = true;
    cellRng.Value2 = ave.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    cellRng.NumberFormat = "##0.00";
    cellRng.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    . . .
}
```

How can code both reference a possibly null object (cellRng) and then, after that check is implemented, actually turn out to be always null (code that runs if it is not null is considered unreachable)?

In the second line below, Resharper offers to remove the code, saying, "Expression is always null"

```
cellRng = _xlSheet5.Cells[rowIdx, colCnt] as Range;
if (cellRng != null)
```

But how is that? How is it that the range assigned to cellRng is seen as always null?

The code in the if block following the code above is tagged by Resharper as "code is heuristically unreachable"

What the Czech!?!?!

Comment: It's just pretty bad with understanding Interop Components. If the code is valid, then ignore ReSharper.

Comment: Does the indexer of `Cells` (which appears to be of type `Range`) return another `Range`?

Comment: This is because _xlSheet5.Cells[rowIdx, colCnt] is not typecasted as Range for Resharper, which is sometimes due Resharper not able to evaluate the Runtime objects. Similar issue happens when a class is used with AOP Cache, which is used and evaluated at runtime, so if you are sure then ignore Resharper